# Storing data in session using jquery and accessing that value in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I store data in session or cookie using jquery or JS and access it in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For cookies:

JavaScript:

```
document.cookie = 'foo=bar';
```

After that code has been run, and you open a page on the same domain with the following command in it:

PHP:

```
echo 'The cookie "foo" had the value ' . $_COOKIE['foo'];
```

The output will be "The cookie "foo" had the value bar".

### For sessions:

You're out of luck, that cannot be done on the client-side, so JavaScript won't help you.

Comment: that was great .... thanks ... in the start I was kinda shocked ppl down voting and stuff.... because I knew we could do this and I got some answers like ... nonononono .... anyways thanks a lot I appreciate it

Comment: hey I have got one more question in javascript 
if I want to store a var in foo what would be the syntax  document.cookie = 'foo='+ bar;   could you please let me know about it

Comment: If `bar` is a variable then yes, `document.cookie = 'foo='+bar` would assign the value of `bar` to the cookie variable `foo`.

Comment: Technically, you could store variables with javascript in a session. You would need to create a php handler for ajax requests and store them server side. This method would be good if you planned to store data over long periods of time or associate the data to an account.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are client side storage. You can have the server emit headers which will set cookies, or you can set cookies with javascript. Session data is stored on the server. Session data can not be set via the client, although you can call a page on the server and have the server set session data. You'll have to have sessions enabled in order to do this. Cookies don't need to have sessions configured in order to work.

Comment: Sessions need cookies enabled as the session id is stored client side in a cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can run an ajax call to the php page and store your session info and the then another ajax call to a php page that dumps the session info out as json and parse that.